# I would like to create an app that connects phone camera/microphone to pc

Tags: android

As the title says i want to create an app that connects the phone camera to pc.I want to do this for my diploma (with some other things but i got those figured out) and i dont know where to start.Is there a book or something like that that would help me learn how to make it.I want it to work kind of like Wo Mic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) API to write android app which can stream phone's camera to PC